# Mapping Entity to DTO doesn't work using NHibernate

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate

I want to map certain properties from Entity to DTO, but it returns result count as 0

Entity:

```cs
public class CustomerForSendToBusinessCentralEntity : BaseEntity
{
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual CustomerEntity Customer { get; set; }
}
```

CustomerEntity:

```cs
public class CustomerEntity : BaseEntity
{
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string LoginName { get; set; }
    public virtual string FirstName { get; set; }
    public virtual string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

DTO I want to map these properties:

```cs
public class CustomerForSendToBusinessCentralDTO
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

This is the query I have written, but it doesn't work:

```cs
CustomerForSendToBusinessCentralEntity cust = null;
CustomerForSendToBusinessCentralDTO customersForSendToBusinessCentralDto = null;
CustomerEntity customer = null;

try
{
    using (var session = _database.OpenSessionBusinessCentral())
    {
        var result = session.QueryOver(() => cust)
            .JoinAlias(() => cust.Customer, () => customer)
            .SelectList(list => list
                .Select(() => customer.FirstName).WithAlias(() => customersForSendToBusinessCentralDto.FirstName)
                .Select(() => customer.LastName).WithAlias(() => customersForSendToBusinessCentralDto.LastName)
                .Select(() => customer.Id).WithAlias(() => customersForSendToBusinessCentralDto.Id)
            )
            .TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToBean<CustomerForSendToBusinessCentralDTO>())
            .Take(_orderCount)
            .List<CustomerForSendToBusinessCentralDTO>();

        return result.ToList();
    }
}
catch (Exception exception)
{
    Log.Error(exception, "{exceptionMessage}", exception.Message);
    throw;
}
```

Comment: This is an attempt to *project* fewer columns using QueryOver, not map an entity to a DTO. Have you tried to use LINQ instead? The syntax is certainly cleaner: `session.Query<Customer>().Select(cust=>new CustomerForSendToBusinessCentralDTO{ Id=cust.Id, FirstName=cust.FirstName, LastName=cust.LastName}).Take(...).ToList()`. You'd have to specify an ORDER BY in either case, as there's no guaranteed result order without an `ORDER BY`